# Error to use @KafkaListener at class level

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I'm trying to use `@KafkaListener` at class level, and use `@KafkaHandler` with `@Payload` at the args to validate the message. I need this because the Topic has more than one type of `Json`. But I'm getting some errors.

First I got:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The class 'br.com.producer.chave.model.Chave' is not in the trusted packages: [java.util, java.lang]. If you believe this class is safe to deserialize, please provide its name. If the serialization is only done by a trusted source, you can also enable trust all (*).`

But `br.com.producer.chave.model.Chave` is the model in `Producer` and I'm in consumer, is another project, anyway, I solve this adding at `KafkaConfig`

```java
configProps.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES,"*");
```

But the `Deserializer` tries to find this class in my consumer, and I got another error:

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: br.com.producer.chave.model.Chave`

I know that when Json serializes data in the producer, it adds the type to the header, and I can disable it.

So, I was reading the documentation and it says to add `JsonDeserializer.TYPE_MAPPINGS` in the producer and in the consumer, and I got the same errors. These are my classes:

Config Producer:
obs: I had 5 different types, but in `TYPE_MAPPINGS` I put only two for test.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Value("${kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Value("${kafka.producer.security.protocol}")
    private String sslSecurityProtocol;

    @Value("${kafka.producer.properties.sasl.mechanism}")
    private String saslMechanism;

    @Value("${kafka.producer.properties.sasl.jaas.config}")
    private String jaasConfig;

    @Value("${kafka.value-serializer}")
    private String valueSerializer;

    @Value("${kafka.key-serializer}")
    private String keySerializer;

    @Value("${kafka.client-id}")
    private String clientId;
    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String,Object> producerFactory() {
        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(JsonSerializer.TYPE_MAPPINGS,
                        "chave:br.com.producer.chave.model.Chave," +
                        "cpfCnpj:br.com.producer.cpfcnpj.model.CpfCnpj");
        serializer.configure(configProps, false);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProperties(), new StringSerializer(), serializer);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<String, Object>(producerFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaAdmin kafkaAdmin() {
        return new KafkaAdmin(configProperties());
    }

    private Map<String,Object> configProperties() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, clientId);
        configProps.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, sslSecurityProtocol);
        configProps.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_MECHANISM, saslMechanism);
        configProps.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG, jaasConfig);
        return configProps;
    }
}
```

Config Consumer:

```java
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class KafkaConfig {
    @Value("${kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Value("${kafka.consumer.group-id}")
    private String groupId;

    @Value("${kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset}")
    private String autoOffsetReset;

    @Value("${kafka.consumer.security.protocol}")
    private String sslSecurityProtocol;

    @Value("${kafka.consumer.properties.sasl.mechanism}")
    private String saslMechanism;

    @Value("${kafka.consumer.properties.sasl.jaas.config}")
    private String jaasConfig;

    @Value("kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit")
    private String autoCommit;

    @Value("${kafka.consumer.ssl.protocol}")
    private String sslProtocol;

    @Value("${kafka.consumer.ssl.trust-store-location}")
    private String sslTruststoreLocation;

    @Value("${kafka.consumer.ssl.trust-store-password}")
    private String sslTruststorePassword;

    @Value("${kafka.consumer.ssl.trust-store-type}")
    private String sslTruststoreType;

    @Value("${kafka.consumer.client-id}")
    private String clientId;


    @Bean
    KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, Object>>

    kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setSyncCommits(Boolean.TRUE);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, Object> consumerFactory() {
        JsonDeserializer deserializer = new JsonDeserializer();
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(JsonDeserializer.TYPE_MAPPINGS,
                "chave:br.com.consumer.psib.domain.model.Chave," +
                        "cpfCnpj:br.com.consumer.psib.domain.model.CpfCnpj");
        configProps.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*");
        deserializer.configure(configProps, false);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(configProperties(), new StringDeserializer(), deserializer,true);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaAdmin kafkaAdmin() {
        return new KafkaAdmin(configProperties());
    }


    private Map<String, Object> configProperties() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, autoOffsetReset);
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, Boolean.valueOf(autoCommit));

        return configProps;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProperties());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }

}
```

And this is my listener:

```java
@Slf4j
@Component
@KafkaListener(
        topics = "${kafka.consumer.topics.chave-pix-negativa.topic}",
        groupId = "${kafka.consumer.group-id}"
)
public class listener {

    @Autowired
    private IListaNegativaInsertUseCase<Chave> chaveInsertUseCase;
    @Autowired
    private IListaNegativaDeleteUseCase<Chave> chaveDeleteUseCase;

    @Autowired
    private IListaNegativaInsertUseCase<CpfCnpj> cpfCnpjInsertUseCase;

    @Autowired
    private IListaNegativaDeleteUseCase<CpfCnpj> cpfCnpjDeleteUseCase;


    @KafkaHandler
    public void listenerCpfCnpj(@Payload CpfCnpj message, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
       //otherthing
    }


    @KafkaHandler
    public void listenerLista(@Payload Chave message, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
     //something

    }

    @KafkaHandler(isDefault = true)
    public void defaulthander (@Payload String m){
        log.error("NAO FOI POSSIVEL {}", m);
    }
}
```

With this config the `TYPE_MAPPINGS` doesn't work, I don't know if I miss something or I'm using it wrong.

I expect the @KafkaHandler validated the payload and goes to the correct handler according to the type of the message.

Comment: OK. Any chances to see a simple project from you to reproduce? Everything looks OK from the code perspective and it is not obvious what is going on.

Comment: Yes, i will provide, i need change somethings and i will give you the repo

Comment: @ArtemBilan Its working now, the only thing that i do was: In pom.xml i've changed the version of the spring-boot-starter-parent from 2.7.8 to 3.0.6, thanks for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But, br.com.producer.chave.model.Chave is the model in Producer and i'm in consumer

The producer needs to share its built models with the consumer as a JAR. Perhaps via Maven dependency, for example.

Otherwise, you have to fallback to using Kafka StringDeserializer and handling the class deserialization on your own.

You would get the exact same error if you tried to manually use `objectMapper.readValue(payload, br.com.producer.chave.model.Chave.class)`, as that class does not exist on your classpath.

If you've copied/re-defined your own `chave` class type, then you're needlessly duplicating code, IMO.

Also trusting `*` is not recommended. You should try to use `java.util,java.lang,br.com.producer,br.com.consumer` instead.

Comment: Its working now, the only thing that i do was: In pom.xml i've changed the version of the spring-boot-starter-parent from 2.7.8 to 3.0.6. The TypeMapper will solve the pkg problem for me, i had same key in both project, and when the deserelializer is called, will get the key in the header of the message and search in TypeMapper to get the new class. thanks for your support!!

Comment: Cool. Yes, for new code, it is recommended to use latest versions. I'm not completely sure how that solves your classpath issues for deserialization, however